# Changing axis to percentage in TimeSeriesChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to show the value on my time chart as percentages. My code is currently

```
    TimeSeries ts = new TimeSeries("Test");
    ts.add(new Month(2,2001), 50);
    ts.add(new Month(2,2002), 70);
    TimeSeriesCollection ts1 = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    ts1.addSeries(ts);



    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart("test", "x", "y", ts1, true, true,false);
    XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getXYPlot();
    NumberAxis axis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
    axis.setTickUnit(new NumberTickUnit(10));
    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#%");
    axis.setNumberFormatOverride(format);
    axis.setRange(0, 100);

    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
```

This does show percentages but it shows them as 1000%,2000% etc. I want them to be 10%,20% etc. Does anyone know where i went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix it by using

```
        format.setMultiplier(1);
```

and changed

```
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#%");
```

to

```
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##%");
```